# Changing error language in Store

Tags: expresso-store

Is there any out of the box way to change error language for the front end of Store, i.e. "expiry" to "expiration"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the store/language/English/lang_store.php file or if you are just wanting to modify error messages you can do something along the lines of:

```
{if error:field_name}Your custom error message here{/if}
```

Comment: Looked in the lang_store file first but didn't see anything for expiry error language (relating to an empty input), so will go with conditionals. Thanks-